# String incrementer problem using rust (codewars)

Tags: rust

im trying to solve the string incrementer problem which is in codewars using rust

> https://www.codewars.com/kata/54a91a4883a7de5d7800009c/train/rust

but when i wrote this code and ran . it came a error

```
error[E0599]: the method `to_string` exists for struct `Chars<'_>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:2:29
   |
2  |       let mut num = s.chars().to_string().filter(|c| "0123456789".contains(c)).collect();
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Chars<'_>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `Chars<'_>: std::fmt::Display`
           which is required by `Chars<'_>: ToString`

error[E0599]: no method named `remove_last` found for reference `&str` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:4:11
  |
4 |         s.remove_last();
```

the real code is

```
fn increment_string(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut num = s.chars().to_string().filter(|c| "0123456789".contains(c)).collect();
    for i in 1..=num.len(){
        s.remove_last();
    }
    num = num.chars().map(|c| c.parse::<u32>().unwrap()) + 1;
    format!("{}{}",s,num);
}
```

can someone help me to rectify this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of `let mut num = s.chars().to_string().filter(|c| "0123456789".contains(c)).collect();` you can write `let mut num: String = s.chars().filter(|c| c.is_numeric()).collect();`.
2. `.pop()` is used for removing the last element from the `String`
3. you don't need `;` at the end of the function

Here is the working code (I've tested it on a few cases): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35d48393fa8ece9a2bb4cdc5c6544fcd
But you can still optimize it, I suppose ;)